# Non zero global section of line bundle and its dual $\implies \mathcal L\cong O_X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a projective integral scheme over $K=\bar{K}$. Suppose that $\Gamma(X,\mathcal L)\neq 0$, $\Gamma(X,\mathcal L^{*})\neq 0$. We want to show that $\mathcal L\cong \mathcal O_X$. There is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19315/global-sections-of-sheaf-and-dual) on a pretty good website but I don't fully understand it. It defines non zero (why ?) morphisms $\mathcal L\to \mathcal L$ and $\mathcal O_X\to \mathcal O_X$ using composition of maps we get with two non zero global sections. Why would the regular sections defining these morphisms would be constant ? Why is an endomorphism of line bundles would an isomorphism ?

In my case we suppose more than in the answer, we have projective. With these assumptions is there another way ? I wanted to say that $X$ is a closed subscheme of some projective space but I think we would need more assumptions on $S$ if $X=\operatorname{Proj}S$.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a point $x\in X$ where the section of $\mathcal L$ and the section of $\mathcal L^*$ do not vanish. Since the fiber of a line bundle over $x$ is a 1-dimensional vector space, it is easy to see that compositions $\mathcal L\to\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal O_X\to\mathcal O_X$ induce non-zero endomorphisms of fibers over $x$, hence they are non-zero. Any endomorphism of line bundle is a multiplication with a regular function (one can prove it locally, using local triviality of a line bundle), and any regular function on a proper connected variety is constant.

Comment: Why would there be a point where they both don't vanish ?

Comment: Perhaps another way to phrase this argument could be: let $s, s’$ be nonzero global sections of $\mathcal{L}$ and its dual, respectively. Then $f=s’(s)$ is a global function on $X$, hence is constant. If $f=0$, then $X=V(s) \cup V(s’)$ is not irreducible (since $s,s’$ are nonzero). Hence $f$ is a nonzero constant, so $s$ never vanishes.

Comment: There is such a point, because vanishing locus of a section is closed, and X is irreducible, as Aphelli said.

Comment: @Aphelli Indeed this is nicely stated, thank you both.

Comment: @Aphelli Actually why does it imply $X=V(s)\cup V(s')$ ? If $x\notin V(s)$ I get that $s_x\in \operatorname{Ker}s'_x$, not necessarily that $s'_x=0$

Comment: If $x \notin V(s)$ then $s_x$ is a generator of $\mathcal{L}$ near $s$. Recall that $V$ means “points where the stalk of the thing lies in the maximal ideal”.